# Date Format Not Recognised

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a range of dates which I have VBA search through to find the cell that contains a date Im looking for - a date picked from a calendar user-form and placed in a text box.
The format of the date in the text box is the same as the format of the range, i.e. dd-mmm (or 11-feb), and the code instructs VBA to search the cell value.
However this is where I am confused. On searching I can find any date but only those after the 10th of the month, for example 10th, or 17th, or 22nd. But it fails to recognise any thing between 01-09.
Why is this and is there any solution?

The code from the calendar to the textbox is

```
shiftcoverUserForm.dateTextBox.Value = Format(calanderuserform.Calendar1.Value, "dd" + "-" + "mmm")
```

and the code to search is

```
Dim Srchdate As Range
Dim srchname As Range
Set Srchdate = Worksheets("Shift Cover").Range("c4:abf4").Find(dateTextBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Srchdate Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Not Found"
```

screenshot of my data is below. Basically the search will find for example 10th Jan but when I want it to find for example 7th Jan it prompts the msgbox "not found

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and sample data

Comment: Side note: `"dd" + "-" + "mmm"` -> `"dd-mmm"`.

Comment: noted thanks. still got the original issue though. I really can't get my head around why it won't recognise 01st-09th

Comment: Are the dates in the range actual dates,  or *text-that-looks-like-dates*? What happens if you change their formatting to General - do they remain `dd-mmm` or display a number?

Comment: they change to a number

Comment: Then I would suggest looking for the actual date/number, and not the formatted text.

Comment: dumb question now but how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Hmmm... on further testing that may not have been a good recommendation.

Comment: Try replacing of `Set Srchdate = Worksheets("Shift Cover").Range("c4:abf4").Find(dateTextBox.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)`  with  `Set Srchdate = Worksheets("Shift Cover").Range("c4:abf4").Find(DateValue(dateTextBox.Value), LookIn:=xlValues)`

Comment: cheers but still a no

Comment: @FaneDuru please don't answer questions in comments.

Comment: @teylyn: How do you suggest to proceed instead of what I did?  To make an answer without being sure that what I proposed will solve his problem? If not, please guide me to a better approach.

Comment: @FaneDuru Post it as an answer and then see what comes back. Amend your answer after the feedback if you want to. That's done all the time.

Comment: @CincinnatiKid We're poking around in the dark here. Please post sample data so the problem can be replicated and a proper answer posted.

Comment: @teylyn iv posted a screenshot in the question. Is this enough? there's really not much more to it other than the code and the sample range. Really need to get this sorted bcos its for a work project but I just really can't understand why it doesn't recognise those dates